# Manga about a boy who participates in battle to expand his god's shrine and uses rope to fight

Tags: gan-kon

I read this manga a few months ago, but I forgot the title.

The story is about a boy who met a lone **god** and participated in battles which would expand her shrine every time he won. I remember the guy using a rope to fight.

I really want to read it again. Hope you guys can help me :)

Answer (score 7):

I'm quite sure it's [**Gan-Kon**](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=70670) (English title: *My Wife Is Beautiful God*).

[image: Volume 1 Cover]

> Tagamori Shinta is a student who routinely confesses with complete sincerity to any girls that he likes, failing every time with good reason. One day, after another failed attempt, he stumbles upon a strange shrine and ends up making the most important wish of his entire life. A romantic comedy packed with action on a celestial scale.

The main character battles with the red thread of fate, which becomes thicker the more affection he has towards the girl (his god).

[image: Chapter 1 Page 46]

After every winning battle, his god gets more territory and her shrine is also upgraded accordingly.